# External SVG Sprite antialias rendering issues

Tags: google-chrome, svg, safari, sprite, antialiasing

I've created an SVG symbol sprite with a bunch of icons in it. When I display them on the page via the `<svg><use xlink:href="file.svg#id"></svg` method, they aren't being antialiased properly in Chrome or Safari (it looks OK in Firefox). SVGs render nicely when using an `<img>` tag, however (see screenshot for comparison).

I've played around with [shape-rendering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering), but it only serves to make the edges look even more exaggerated when set to `crispEdges`. I've tried adding the attribute to the paths directly in the SVG and to the whole shape via CSS to the same effect.

This only occurs when the icons are scaled down—at full size they look fine.

### [image: SVG rendering: img tag vs sprite]

**Edit**: Here's the SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 30 30" aria-labelledby="checkbox-title" id="checkbox">
    <title id="checkbox-title">Checkbox</title>
    <path d="M0 0v30h30V0H0zm28 28H2V2h26v26zm-2.2-18L23 7.2l-11 11L7.8 14 5 16.8l7 7L25.8 10zm-18 5.4l3.5 3.5.7.7.7-.7L23 8.6l1.4 1.4L12 22.4l-5.6-5.6 1.4-1.4z"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

Here's how I'm embedding it in my HTML file:

```
<svg class="svg-icon svg-icon--checkbox">
  <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/images/icons.svg#checkbox"></use>
</svg>
```

The CSS I'm applying directly to the SVG is:

```
.svg-icon {
  fill: #333;
  height: 1rem;
  width: 1rem;
}
```

And the entire computed CSS for the SVG (including inherited styles, user agent styles, etc.):

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: #333;
display: inline;
fill: #333;
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 15.9625px;
height: 15.9531px;
line-height: 21.5494px;
order-collapse: separate;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
transform-origin: 7.96875px 7.96875px;
width: 15.9531px;
```

---

- Chrome 50.0.2661.102
- Safari 9.1
- Mac OS X 10.11.4

Comment: You should add the content of file.svg (at least the bit for the cross icon) to the question and also any CSS applied to the use

Comment: Is it possible it's a viewBox issue instead? We could test some things if we had more code, as @RobertLongson requested.

Comment: @RobertLongson Yeah, good point! I just updated that question with all the relevant code.

Comment: The CSS you have posted doesn't match your code. There is nothing with the class `svg-icon`.  Can you create a working snippet please that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Ah, I didn't notice that! I've updated the example above. I can't create a JSFiddle because of CORS issues with pulling in external SVGs, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm seeing these artifacts in Chrome even without scaling.